# Problems with mysql IF-Statement: delivering changed values

Tags: mysql

```
if (preise.kond_basis_preis > 0,preise.kond_basis_preis, a.bruttopreis) as bruttopreis,
preise.kond_basis_preis,
a.bruttopreis as brutto
```

delivers as values:

```
4.659999847412109   
4.66    
4.66
```

What causes this?

Server Version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic causes this.  Your first line contains an implicit computation.

Try

```
ROUND(if (preise.kond_basis_preis > 0,preise.kond_basis_preis, a.bruttopreis),2) as bruttopreis,
```

and you'll get the twp decimal places to the right of the `.` as you expect.

Read this. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)